# export adding extra characters

Tags: bash, awk, export, saucelabs

I am trying to get my tunnel ID from sauce labs... To get this I am doing the following:

```
SAUCE_TUNNELL_IDENTIFIER=$(curl https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/myusername/tunnels -u myusername:mykey)
```

This returns `["my-tunnel-id"]`

So I want to get rid of the [] and export my tunnel id..

Here is the export and removal of `[]`

```
export SAUCE_TUNNELL_IDENTIFIER=$(echo $SAUCE_TUNNELL_IDENTIFIER | awk '{print substr($0, 2, length($0) -2)}')
```

When I do an `export -p`, I see it like this `"\"my-tunnel-id\""`

But if I just do an `echo $SAUCE_TUNNELL_IDENTIFIER`, I do not see the exta `"\` in my variable. Where is this coming from? Also, any help making this into one better command would also be appreciated! :)

Comment: Maybe try `export SAUCE_TUNNELL_IDENTIFIER="$(curl https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/myusername/tunnels -u myusername:mykey| tr -d'[]')"`. tr(anslate) -d(elete) characters ... in case you also want to strip the double quotes around the tunnel-id, try `... | tr -d '[]"' ...` instead in aforementioned translate part ... HTH

Comment: i gave it a try and received `tr: invalid option -- '['`

Comment: Hm, sometimes - at least on my OS X bash, spaces are annoying, like `echo '["tunneld-id"]' | tr -d'[]'`yields `tr: illegal option -- [`whilst `echo '["tunneld-id"]'| tr -d '[]'`happily echoes `"tunneld-id"`;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server is returning a JSON array; you could use something like `jq` to extract just the single element in the array, but for something this simple, you can just use parameter expansion.

```
$ SAUCE_TUNNELL_IDENTIFIER=$(curl https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/myusername/tunnels -u myusername:mykey)
$ SAUCE_TUNNELL_IDENTIFIER=${SAUCE_TUNNELL_IDENTIFIER//[]\"[]}
$ echo "$SAUCE_TUNNELL_IDENTIFIER"
my-tunnel-id
```

Update:

I assumed the identifier could not contain brackets or quotes. A safer, though longer, alternative is to strip each *outer* character one by one.

```
$ STI=$(curl ...)
$ STI=${STI#[}
$ STI=${STI#\"}
$ STI=${STI%]}
$ STI=${STI%\"}
```

and at this point I may as well show how to use `jq` to do this:

```
$ curl ... | jq -r '.[0]'
my-tunnel-id
```

`.` represents the incoming JSON; `[0]` extracts the first element; `-r` tells `jq` to output the raw string instead of the quoted JSON string (`my-tunnel-id` instead of `"my-tunnel-id"`).

Comment: FYI you left off the $ in the echo... but this works! thanks!